# How to sort 14,000 entries?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Right, the gist of my issues is described [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/2yovm7/columns_still_not_aligning_properly/), however I will explain briefly, however the link also has pictures of my issue.

I have a workbook of 14,000 or so entries and I need to search and sort them to find around 409 entries within this workbook. I not only need to find the same 'WONUM', but the data associated with this WONUM in the rows. I have attempted to search using a few formulas such as ISNA, MATCH and LOOKUP, however I am either getting nothing back or it fails or it just gives me a whole number.

[In this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7taxl.jpg), I've created a mini test workbook whereby the figures I need to find are in column B, 'Failed WONUM' and the data to be searched is in column C, 'WONUM'. Column A, 'Matched WONUM' has been done manually to show what I need from this search but will ultimately house whatever formula I am using with someones help. as you can see, what is in 'Matched WONUM' is not (and shouldn't be) aligned with 'Failed WONUM' but with 'WONUM'.

To summarise, values from column B need to be searched for in column C, and any matches to return with the corresponding data to the correct row.

Comment: Question about your sample: why is the first green row: 50631741 marked green and not 'NO MATCH'?

Comment: Why did you tag the question "mysql"? Edit: or "excel-vba" for that matter. You most probably need Excel formulae.

Comment: If the question is basically on Reddit, then it would need to be added here as well (though the acknowledgement of the x-post is appreciated). In the meantime I think this needs to be closed as not being self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look for either number or number as string:

> =IFERROR(MATCH(F1+0,A:A,0),MATCH(F1&"",A:A,0))

NOTE:this refers to F1 as search value and A of the same ws as range.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for helping, however this isn't working. I'm not bothered about conditional formatting at the moment; forgetting about what I said above, I just want a way to find 409 values in the WONUM column. The formula you gave me isn't returning the WONUM's but instead returning whole numbers (such as 30, 10 etc). I'm very desperate to do this asap and may do this manually but I would need a way to do this every week which isn't possible as the 409 is growing every week. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I may not be quite understanding what is data before processing and what of your example is the required results of processing but the green highlighting on the right is easy with Conditional Formatting. Select ColumnsC:I and  HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=MATCH($C1,$B:$B,0)>0
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd> with green fill, OK, OK.

At this point it may be advisable to add an index, say with `=row()` in Row1 of a spare column, copied down to suit and then that column selected copied, and Paste Special, Values.

ColumnsC:H might be sorted by colour and for those with green highlighting then sorted by ColumnC.

I am not sure about ColumnA but if already highlighted, that Column might be sorted independently by colour green and then numerically. With for green ColumnA will now align with ColumnsC:I and ColumnsA:B may be returned to their original order by sorting the entire sheet on the index column.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for helping, however this isn't working. I'm not bothered about conditional formatting at the moment; forgetting about what I said above, I just want a way to find 409 values in the WONUM column. The formula you gave me isn't returning the WONUM's but instead returning whole numbers (such as 30, 10 etc). I'm very desperate to do this asap and may do this manually but I would need a way to do this every week which isn't possible as the 409 is growing every week. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Formatting aside, just paste the following formula in cell A1 and copy down through column A:

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(C1,B:B, 0), C1), "NO MATCH")
```

(Using C:C instead of C1, as you had attempted to do in your example, should work fine too, but you had the order of arguments reversed for what you were trying to do.)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for helping, however this isn't working. I'm not bothered about conditional formatting at the moment; forgetting about what I said above, I just want a way to find 409 values in the WONUM column. The formula you gave me isn't returning the WONUM's but instead returning whole numbers (such as 30, 10 etc). I'm very desperate to do this asap and may do this manually but I would need a way to do this every week which isn't possible as the 409 is growing every week. Please help!

Comment: I have edited my answer above. Does it work for you now?

Comment: No, I've changed the columns around in your formula however still its only returning 6 of the 7 results

Comment: Wait a min, seems like its OK, lemme check it with the main workbook

Comment: OK, I've put it in the main workbook and it seems to find the figures under WONUM correctly, however now the issue is when I filter the search column (Column B), Anything past column D, WONUM (same as Work Order), does not correspond to the search in Column B. This is the whole point of the exercise, to find the corresponding data... I.e. Work order in D6, is not the same as in B1 or C1

http://i.imgur.com/IMijPRU.jpg

Comment: Hi @jetblast787, in your latest example image, you still have the columns reversed... Column D should be your lookup value, and Column C should be your lookup array. So the formula you use should be =IFERROR(IF(MATCH(D:D, C:C, 0), D:D), "NO MATCH"). Not =IFERROR(IF(MATCH(C:C, D:D, 0), C:C), "NO MATCH") as you have it.